# Website Scraping Using Regex trying to extract integers

Tags: php, xpath, web, web-scraping, domdocument

I'm having trouble to extract the integers between the brackets from this website.

Part of markup from the website:

```
<span class="b-label b-link-number" data-num="(322206)">Music &amp; Video</span>
<span class="b-label b-link-number" data-num="(954218)">Toys, Hobbies &amp; Games</span>
<span class="b-label b-link-number" data-num="(502981)">Kids, Baby &amp; Maternity</span>
```

How do I extract the integers between the brackets?

Desired output:

```
322206
954218
502981
```

Should I use Regex since they got the same class name (but not Regex to get between brackets since there are other unwanted elements inside bracket as well from the source code).

Normally, this would be the way I use to extract information:

```
<?php
//header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$grep = new DoMDocument();
@$grep->loadHTMLFile("http://global.rakuten.com/en/search/?tl=&k=");
$finder = new DomXPath($grep);
$class = "b-list-item";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$class')]");

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $span = $node->childNodes;
    $search = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'(',')');
    $categories = str_replace($search, '', $span->item(0)->nodeValue);
    echo '<br>' . '<font color="green">' . $categories . '  ' . '</font>' ;

}
?>
```

but since the data I want is inside the tag, how do I extract them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding on your current code, its simply straight forward, just change that `$class` to that class you desire and use `->getAttribute()` to get those `data-num`'s:

```
$grep = new DoMDocument();
@$grep->loadHTMLFile("http://global.rakuten.com/en/search/?tl=&k=");
$finder = new DomXPath($grep);
$class = "b-link-number"; // change the span class
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$class')]"); // target those

$numbers = array();
foreach ($nodes as $node) { // for every found elemenet
    $link_num = $node->getAttribute('data-num'); // get the attribute `data-num`
    $link_num = str_replace(['(', ')'], '', $link_num); // simply remove those parenthesis
    $numbers[] = $link_num; // push it inside the container
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($numbers);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<span[^>)()]*\((\d+)\)[^>]*>
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/iM2wF9/10